# Newline in PHP command line

Tags: php, newline

I'm running a PHP script via the command line and trying to get output printed on new lines. I've tried all of the usual suspects (`\n,\r,\l`) but nothing is working. I'm accessing my Ubuntu server using PuTTY over SSH. Here's my code:

`echo($string.'\r');`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use double quotes:

```
echo($string."\r");
             ^  ^
```

single quoted strings do not honor ANY metacharacters, except the backslash itself.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. Thanks! Someone else also mentioned using the PHP_EOL constant (but then deleted their answer - not sure why). Both are great solutions. Thanks!

Comment: PHP_EOL is handy if the file you're producing is targeted for 'local' usage. But if you're (say) on a Windows box, producing a file for a Unix target, then PHP_EOL's useless, because it'll contain the Windows EOL characters.

Comment: @danielfaraday: When you tried printing this with single quotes...did you not get a literal `\r`? That should have been your hint.

Comment: The PHP_EOL constant is meant to be cross-platform compatible. EG: if you use PHP_EOL on a linux distro it is defined as "\n", on a windows distro it is defined as "\r\n", on mac distro it is defined as "\r" Resource: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php.h

Comment: @MarcB yes the "value" is platform SPECIFIC, however the constant of PHP_EOL is not. It is variable depending on the platform the calling  script is executed on. Such as writing an application or framework to be distributed to run and be "COMPATIBLE" with other platforms. Saving a text file on one platform to be read on another platform, one should expect the newline character native to the platform the text file was generated on. Thusly making your application platform specific not the PHP_EOL constant.

Comment: you're not understanding what I'm saying. Yes, PHP code using php_eol will be "cross-platform". but **FILES** you generate with that php code WON'T be.

Comment: I do understand, you are arguing that newlines within static files are not cross-platform. I am stating that `echo PHP_EOL` would return the newline character for the platform it is executed on. That is why I defined each return value based on the executing platform and linked to the source file that determines which newline to draw depending on platform.

Comment: exactly. you have a php script which generates some kind of .txt file. you then send that .txt file to someone else, and they're on a different platform with different eol characters. That's where PHP_EOL is useless. the recipient doesn't have php, they just have a text file, and that file has the eol chars of the person who MADE the file.

Comment: At that point PHP_EOL is not placed in the text file, a newline is... I never claimed that it generates cross-platform compatible newlines (nothing does). I said "The PHP_EOL constant is meant to be cross-platform compatible", on the platform of which it is used. `echo "\n"` is platform specific to linux and will always be. `echo PHP_EOL` is not specific to any platform but is compatible with all platforms of which it is executed on. The resulting file's compatibility is irrelevant.

Answer (score 21):

You can concatenate the `PHP_EOL` constant.

```
echo 'Hi, Im great!' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'And Handsome too' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: This is more flexible to use in any OS. `"\r"` gives blank lines when we use `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes **echo "next line\n";**

Answer (score 2):

For the command line script, it's recommended to use `PHP_EOL`.

Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

```
PHP_EOL (string)
The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 5.0.2
```

It make your script executable across platform.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer not work for me. 
my try is `"\r\n"`

```
echo 'This is some text before newline';
echo "\r\n"."text in new line";
//OR

echo 'This is some text before newline'."\r\n"."text in new line";
```

cmd output will be:

This is some text before newline

text in new line

Answer (score -1):

PHP there are several many ways. But i think this is what you need

```
echo $array."<br>";
```